# What is the difference between tslints "typedef" and typescript compilers "noImplicitAny"?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am using tslint to lint my typescript code. I have been searching for a while but couldn't find out what differences (if any) exist between using the typescript compiler option `noImplicitAny` and the following config in tslint:

```
"no-inferrable-types": [true]
"typedef": [
  true,
  "property-declaration",
  "variable-declaration",
  // ... etc ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differences exist and they are pretty big.

NoImplicite any will throw error when variable is recognised as `any` AND is not typed directly e.g.:

```js
let arr = []
arr.forEach(item => item) // Variable 'arr' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.(7005)

// but
[1,2,3].map(item => item) // OK
```

In second case item type is not declared (like in first one) however TS compiler knows what `item` variable is (map on `Array<number>` has to be called with `number`

Also code like this:

```js
let arr = []
arr.forEach((item: any) => item) // OK
```

will not throw error. `item` is typed as any, but it explicite, not implicite.

I case of linter rules they are just force you to add type definition, so this code `[1,2,3].map(item => item)` will pass compilation, however linter will makr is as error.

Comment: Ah, so practically NoImplicitAny uses the TypeScript logic to infer as many types as possible and only forces me to prevent any-Types, while tslint forces me to type everything.

Comment: Exactly, also you can check `no-unsafe-any` rule in TS, it prevent from any types also explicite ones (e.g. `(arg: any) => 42`).